# How to split serial input into messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial

I have 2 serial ports on Raspberry Pi. Currently, the code is reading data from port 1 and writing it on port 2 and vice versa. What I am trying to do is split the input that I am reading from both ports and split it into different messages (group of character) based on a specified character (for example # or !)

Also, how can I modify the current 'for' loop in the end so that I can split the messages for both ports, currently the code is only written to split data from 1 port.

I have already tried split() and it gives a type error. The reason can be serial input might be in a different type

```
import serial
ser1 = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', timeout=2)
ser2 = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1', timeout=2)
print (ser1)
print (ser2)
ser1_list = []
ser2_list = []

while (True):
    data1 = ser1.readlines()
    data2 = ser2.readlines()
    if data1 or data2:
        ser1_list.extend(data1)
        ser2.writelines(data1)
        byte_split1 = ser1_list.split("1")
        ser2_list.extend(data2)
        ser1.writelines(data2)
        byte_split2 = ser1.split('1')
        for x in byte_split1:
            print(x)
    else:
        break
ser1.close()
ser2.close()
```

Example for the expected result:
If the input is:

```
abcde#fghi#jklmnop#
```

it would output:

```
abcde
fghi
jklmnop
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're trying to set up something like a chat between the two locations.  Please consider looking up how to do that in canonical fashion:

Split this into parallel processes, one each for `ser1 => ser2` and the other for `ser2 => ser1`.  Each process will handle communication in its own direction.

This allows you to write one **listener** for each port; your two processes will be identical, except that you instantiate them with the ports in opposite order.  Each listener gathers traffic until it gets to a separator; at that point, it writes the buffer contents up to that point and moves the buffer pointer.  There are plenty of I/O packages to do this for you; you're merely "chunking" the stream with that separator character.

That should be enough guidance and references for you to find the examples you need.

Comment: I already have ports talking to each other and writing the data. I am looking for something such as a split function, which is currently not working for me, becuase the input data is being stored as list instead of string. 
Can you share any example of what you mean ?